# How can I append the values which I got from the def function return value to DataFrame?

Tags: python

How can I append the values which I got from the def function return value to DataFrame? I would like to return a list from a def function which give me scalar for each loop, but the programm shows me

> TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable.

```
def para(x, y):
    z = x + y
    return z

x = [1,2,3]
y = [4,5,6]
list_z = []

for i in range(2):
    z = para(x[i], y[i])
    list_z.append(z[0])
print(list_z)
```

Comment: Please share your expected output

Comment: Do `list_z.append(z)` and you'll get `[5, 7]``, the `para` method return a INT, you cannot do `some_int[0]`

Comment: My expected output should be like a list [5,7,9].

Comment: a) If you actually meant a pandas DataFrame rather than a list-of-lists, then simply `df = pd.DataFrame({'x': x, 'y': y})` and b) pandas DataFrames have builtin methods, so you can simply do `df['z'] = df['x'] + df['y']` without needing your function `para`

Answer (score 0):

1. First error is that `para` method return an `int` and you try to access something on it, you can't do `4[0]` that not possible
2. Then you use `range(2)` that generates values `[0,1]` so you're missing last values of arrays, use `range(3)` or direcrly yhe length of the arrays

```
def para(x, y):
    z = x + y
    return z

x = [1, 2, 3]
y = [4, 5, 6]
list_z = []

for i in range(len(x)):
    z = para(x[i], y[i])
    list_z.append(z)

print(list_z)  # [5, 7, 9]
```

---

Improvement, use `zip` to iterate on both arrays at same time, on values

```
for x_val, y_val in zip(x, y):
    list_z.append(para(x_val, y_val))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you actually meant a pandas DataFrame rather than manually building a list-of-lists, then simply declare it:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': x, 'y': y})

>>> df
   x  y
0  1  4
1  2  5
2  3  6
```

[pandas DataFrames](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) have builtin methods for operations like +,-,/,*, so you can simply do:

```
df['z'] = df['x'] + df['y']
```

without needing your function `para`:

```
>>> df
   x  y  z
0  1  4  5
1  2  5  7
2  3  6  9
```